# proper http headers to send when switching blog from one domain to another

Tags: php, apache, http

Just wondering what the exact correct header is to send along when I redirect requests from one server (eg. abc.com) to another (eg. def.com/blog/).

I've got the redirects working right, but always get confused as to the exact header to send along with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
Oliver

Comment: Do you mean the 'Location' header?  Can you explain more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP you would do it like this:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://def.com/blog/');
```

You'd change "301 Moved Permanently" to "302 Found" if you are not sure it's permanent.

Comment: Cool thanks. I'm actually doing via apache, so I'll just send a long a R=301 flag in the RewriteRule. Thanks duuuuude.

Answer (score 0):

The header that indicates the new location is the `Location` header:

```
Location: http://def.com/blog/
```

If the change is permanent, you send a 301 response code (Permanent Redirect) so that clients may cache the forward.